# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable Python issues with loops (beginner)

Tags: python, typeerror

Ignoring any current issues with avsterr, I want to call the defined function avsterr to run x amount of times where x is length of my list(). `barcodeCounter` defines the max length of the list. I am not sure how to write the syntax and what type of loop I should use (for, while, if).

`for _ in barcodeCounter:
        (av,st) = avsterr(topr[barcodeCounter],toprseq[barcodeCounter])`
gives me "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

```
def avsterr(x,z):
        ave = len(x)/len(z)
        ssq = 0.0
        for y in x:
                ssq += (y-ave)*(y-ave)
        var = ssq / (len(x)-1)        sdev = math.sqrt(var)
        stderr = sdev / math.sqrt(len(x))
        return (ave,stderr)
```

I hope this is enough info. I appreciate any explanations you can give to help me better understand python.

Comment: tried for _ in xrange(0, barcodeCounter): ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `range()` method. You can iterate an int in this way:

```
In [1]: for y in range(10):
   ...:     print y
   ...:     
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Changing it to `range(barcodeCounter)` indeed fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, just worked through my equation some and it did not fix my issue entirely. I built in a print statement `print "%i %f +/- %f" % (barcodeCounter, av, st)
print _` and it returned `2 10.000000 +/- 21.813604

0

2 10.000000 +/- 21.813604
1
2 10.000000 +/- 21.813604
2`
So it is running from 0 to barcodeCounter, but not using the data from topr[barcodeCounter] or toprseq[barcodeCounter]. Do you know how/explain how to make that work?

Comment: Can you show me the initial values of toprseq, toprseq and  barcodeCounter?

Comment: I can but I figured out the issue. In the original statement `for _ in barcodeCounter:
(av,st) = avsterr(topr[barcodeCounter],toprseq[barcodeCounter])` I needed to change `topr[barcodeCounter]` to `topr[_]`. Simple mistake. Thanks!